# Defining path using #define in C

Tags: c, linux, c-preprocessor

I want to define a path like this:

```
#define PATH /abc/xyz/lmn
```

This PATH is a directory which has files foo1, foo2, foo3, ... foo115.

How can I use this #define in the "open" call to open foo1, foo2, ... foo115 ?

I want to basically do this using the directive:

```
fd = open("/abc/xyz/lmn/foo1", O_RDONLY);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#define PATH "/abc/xyz/lmn"

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   char file2open[256];
   int i;

   for (i = 1; i <= 115; i++)
   {
      sprintf (file2open, "%sfoo%d", PATH, i);
      fd = open (file2open, O_RDONLY)
      ......
      close (fd);
   }

}
```

Comment: Since you're using sprintf anyway, wouldn't a const char* be better than the define?

Comment: I'm old school (maybe just old) and #define is my habit - const char* is just as good :)

Comment: The next question is, does the OP really want this to be a compile-time constant?  Is there a chance this path will change?

Comment: based upon `How can I use this #define in the "open" call to open foo1, foo2, ... foo115 ? ` I say no

Answer (score 1):

```
#define PATH "/some/path/to/foo/files"

for (int i = 0; 1 < SomeNumberOfFiles; i++)
{
    char carray[256] = strcat(PATH, "foo");
    carray = strcat(carray, char(i));
    //Do something with the carray filename
}
```

I may have mixed in some C++, sorry. I tried to keep it as C as a I could.

Answer (score 0):

For example, to open `foo42` you could do:

```
#define PATH  "/abc/xyz/lmn"
fd = open(PATH "/foo42", O_RDONLY);
```