# string concatenation using #define in C

Tags: c, linux, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

I am trying to [concatenate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/c-string-concatenation) strings and `2/3` strings are paths and are [defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690265/defining-path-using-define-in-c) in `#define`

For example:

```
#define BASE_PATH "foo/bar"
#define BIN_PATH "baz/bin"
```

I want to be able to direct to the predefined paths. An example use case would be viewing the contents of that folder.

```
char path_of_executable[256];
printf ("%s \n",executable);
snprintf(path_of_executable, sizeof 256, "%s,%s,%s",BASE_PATH,executable,BIN_PATH);
printf("%s \n",path_of_executable);
chdir(path_of_executable);
execlp("ls","ls","-l",NULL);
```

The path_of_executable is printed out as `/fo`

I am not able to direct to that path but instead the files in the current folder are printed out. Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `sizeof 256`, which translates to `sizeof int`, which apparently 4 on your platform. That's why the resulting string doesn't exceed 4 characters (including the null-terminator). Use `sizeof path_of_executable` instead.

Comment: Woha!. But why can't I change to that directory? . I take back my question

Comment: The additional `,` between `%s` created the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `sizeof 256` with `sizeof( path_of_executable )`

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
snprintf(path_of_executable, sizeof 256, "%s,%s,%s",BASE_PATH,executable,BIN_PATH);
```

replace `sizeof 256` with sizeof(path_of_executable)